# Linux command inside C code: /* treat as comment?

Tags: linux, command-line, c

In C, I want to run linux command. Namely,

```
int status;
status=system("lftp ftp://192.168.1.1 -e "mget -E /2015/Date*/*Snap/*.csv");
```

The `*` above is wildcard matching.

The C compiler thinks this is comment:
`/* and */`

How do modify my call do the C compiler won't think this is comment.

Comment: You need to escape nested quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\` character to [escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) problematic characters:

```
int status;
status = system("lftp ftp://192.168.1.1 -e \"mget -E /2015/Date*\/*Snap/*.csv\"");
```

Also, your original code had mismatched double-quote characters. You have to close both the inner and outer set.